# How do I return for a visit after a 10-year ban?

Tags: visas, usa, uk-citizens, visa-bans

I overstayed my visa waiver in 2008 and was given a 10 year ban, which will be up in June next year. Can anyone tell me what I need to do to be able to visit friends next year when the ban is up?

Comment: Which country are you trying to go to?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I reckon it's the US, given the 10-year ban and the word "visa waiver" being used

Comment: By how long did you overstay?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you're talking about the US, you will need a B2 or B1/B2 visa, which is normally valid for unlimited entries for 10 years.

Of course, given your black history, they could give less, or even refuse you. After all, if you overstayed once, why wouldn't you do it again? The documentation you present at the interview essentially has to satisfactorily answer that question.